# Modifying `tail -f` output in real time

Tags: bash, sed

The logs for my work are output with a | instead of a newline, making them incredibly difficult to read. What I do now is copy and paste them into vim and run `:%s/|/\r/g` to replace all pipe's with a new line.

I'd love to be able to do this in real time in the `tail -f` output of the logs. So instead of having to copy and paste it (or run `sed` on the log file), I could just read the logs right away as they are written to the file, with the pipe separator replaced with new lines.

Is there a way to do this? (I can't modify the line separator for the log output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
tail -f <log file> | tr \| \n | less
```

or some such might work.  Might take some fiddling.

Comment: tail -f <log file> | tr \| '[\n*]' seems to work. Awesome, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe the `tail -f` output to `sed` and run the same regexp you run with `vim` (escaping added):

```
tail -f file | sed -e s/\|/\\n/g -
```